# Performing requests using WebRequest and a Stream

Tags: c#, stream, webrequest

```
public class MyWebRequest
{
    private WebRequest request;
    private Stream dataStream;

    private string status;

    public String Status
    {
        get
        {
            return status;
        }
        set
        {
            status = value;
        }
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url)
    {
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post.

        request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url, string method)
        : this(url)
    {
        if (method.Equals("GET") || method.Equals("POST"))
        {
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = method;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Method Type");
        }
    }

    public MyWebRequest(string url, string method, string data)
        : this(url, method)
    {
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = data;
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Get the request stream.
        dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
    }

    public string GetResponse()
    {
        // Get the original response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        this.Status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

        // Get the stream containing all content returned by the requested server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        // Read the content fully up to the end.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
}
```

I saw this code and was analyzing it. I searched for the `WebRequest` class at `msdn` and understood it, but I don't understand why I have to use a `Stream` to perform the requests. I don't know what a stream is, and why it is needed. Can somebody help me? Also, can somebody explain to me the following two lines?

```
            // Get the request stream.
            dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

The stream gets data, and then I write data to the stream, not the `WebRequest` object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The GetRequestStream is used to initiate send data to internet resources.
Also it used to return stream instance for sending data to internet resources.

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with an HTTP server, you need to make an HTTP request ([examples](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/)). Now you actually send that request as a series of bytes via a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx). A stream is really just a series of bytes.

Most I/O operations (including files or network sockets) are buffered. That means you put bytes in a buffer repeatedly, and when that buffer gets full enough, it is actually sent. The stream is really just an abstraction for that. So really you are only sending bytes over the network in those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN "Provides a generic view of a sequence of bytes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx). I Stream is an abstraction of various objects you might want to read or write data from. Specific examples are [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) for reading and writing to disk, and a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). [Take a look at the other types that inherit from Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

The two lines you highlight are how you send data in the `WebRequest`. Imagine an HTTP request, when you make the request some data is sent to the server. When You're using a `WebRequest` you write this data by getting the request stream and writing bytes to it.